# How to restore the iPhone as a new phone with the same OS version?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

I have an iPhone 5s. It currently has iOS 8.4.1 on it.  I want to restore it as a new phone, but retain iOS 8.4.1.

Is this possible?  Or will iTunes force iOS 9.x onto the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > General > Reset > "Erase All Content and Settings"

[Erase all content and settings - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274)

Answer (score 0):

Erase and Reset from the iOS device. Disconnect from Wi-Fi and make sure iOS 9 isn't downloaded.